# Are the values of array elements defined upon defining an array?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, initialization

I feel quite silly asking this, but I couldn't find a definite answer anywhere. in vb.net, how are the array elements defined (if they are defined) for, for example:

```
Dim myarray(5) as int
```

does, at this point in time, myarray(3) for example have a defined value? If so, what is it?

Comment: whats the basic work you want to do?

Comment: have a function that returns an array of integers, and fills some or all values. In case it is not filled, it should be 0. This seems to be the current behaviour, but I'm not sure if this is explicitly so in the manual, or undefined behaviour that may change at any point in the future.

Comment: Well by using current line it declare the array with size 5. and if array(3) contain any value then you can fetch it otherwise it gives you nothing.

Comment: Am I sure (as far as the language manual is concerened) that that value will be 0 if it's not explicitly set? I couldn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MSDN documentation for the [Dim statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx):

> If you declare the length of an array but do not initialize its
>   elements, each element is initialized as if it were a separate
>   variable.

Essentially, value types will be initialized to their default value (0 for numeric types), and reference types will be initialized to Nothing.